# Instant Article Builder - Como selecionar duas áreas/elementos com conteúdo para o artigo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk

Minha página possui o resumo da matéria e o conteúdo em elementos separados, eu precisaria mostrar ambos no instant-article, mas não posso alterar a estrutura HTML da página.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/builder

```
<div class="summary-news">
    <div class="summary-content">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <ul>  
            <li> Item 1</li> 
            <li> Item 2</li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Other content -->
</div>

<div class="text">
    <!-- Main content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Traduza sua postagem, aqui é o stackoverflow pt-br ficara mais fácil de conseguir que alguém te ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução através dos recursos da ferramenta:

Adicionei um seletor no pai comum e selecionei todo o conteúdo permitido e não permitido nas regras, respectivamente, ***Pass Through*** e ***Ignore***.

Seletores no ***Pass Through***:
.summary-content,.summary-news,.slot-g,.text

```
<div class="ia-content">
    <div class="summary-news">
        <div class="summary-content">
            <h3>Summary</h3>
            <ul>  
                <li> Item 1</li> 
                <li> Item 2</li>
                <li> ... </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <!-- Other content -->
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        <!-- Main content -->
    </div>
</div>
```